# Twisted reactor after specific period of time

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

Is there a way to stop `reactor.run()` after specific time, f.e 10 mins, via `reactor.stop()` and `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)`

Sample:

```
import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, DeferredList
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import connectWS
from protocol import WampClientFactory, WampClientProtocol

class SMSManagementProtocol(WampClientProtocol):
    def showEvent(self, topicUri, result):
        print "EVENT:", topicUri,result
    def onSessionOpen(self):
        self.prefix("event", "http://test.tv/subscribe_public")
        self.subscribe('psevent:on_sms_delivered', self.showEvent)
        self.publish("event:send_sms", {'sms_text':'test','phone_number':29999999,'user_name':'test'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sms_factory = WampClientFactory("ws://xx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx", debugWamp = True)
    sms_factory.protocol = SMSManagementProtocol
    connectWS(sms_factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Is it possible to stop the reactor like this?

```
def check_stop_flag():
if reactor.run(600):
    reactor.stop()
lc = task.LoopingCall(check_stop_flag)
lc.start(600)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule any function call after a time delay with [`reactor.callLater`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html):

```
reactor.callLater(60 * 10, reactor.stop)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when I put it at the end it does not start (reactor.run()) at all.

Comment: You have to put `reactor.callLater` **before** `reactor.run`